# sorting row data in table PHP?

Tags: php, sql, echo

i have a table being echo'd from a single query to a table in our database and i get it to echo out the following table;

http://www.skulldogs.com/dev/testview.php

i want it to sort the "yellow" rows under the correct green rows where the "mainToon" name matches for example:

high voltege

--REAL MCCOY

--Cpt Hook

riazall

-- Valeside

my code to echo the above page is;

```
<?php

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `members`");
  echo "<table border='1'>
  <tr>
  <th>Character ID</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>MainToon</th>
  <th>toonCategory</th>
  </tr>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $characterID = $row['characterID'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        $startDateTime = $row['startDateTime'];
        $logonDateTime = $row['logonDateTime'];
        $logoffDateTime = $row['logoffDateTime'];
        $location = $row['location'];
        $role = $row['role'];
        $vouchedBy = $row['vouchedBy'];
        $positionHeld = $row['positionHeld'];
        $remarks = $row['remarks'];
        $afkNotice = $row['afkNotice'];
        $toonCategory = $row['toonCategory'];
        $mainToon = $row['mainToon'];
        $watch = $row['watch'];

    if ($toonCategory == 'Main Toon') {
        echo "<tr bgcolor='#00FF00'>"; }
    else {
        echo "<tr bgcolor='#FFFF00'>"; }
    echo "<td>" . $characterID . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $name . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $mainToon . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $toonCategory . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  }
    echo "</table>";

?>
```

at the moment i am not echo the other data until i can figure out how to display this table accordingly. can it be done this way?

this is how i want to display the table;

http://www.skulldogs.com/dev/mockup.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an `ORDER BY` clause to your sql:

```
SELECT * FROM `members` ORDER BY toonCategory;
```

If there are other values above and below "Main Toon", You can order by a boolean:

```
SELECT * FROM `members` ORDER BY toonCategory = 'Main Toon' DESC;
```

EDIT:

Now I see what you are after as you have put up the example, try:

```
SELECT * FROM `members` ORDER BY CONCAT(MainToon, Name);
```

if the blank spaces are empty strings or:

```
SELECT * FROM `members` ORDER BY COALESCE(MainToon, Name) DESC, Name;
```

if the blank rows are null.

Comment: it only orders them in the table view by "category" not links the toon with its "ALT" (second toon!) which can be found in the "mainToon" echo.

Comment: @StephenJackson I've 2 possible new answers - hopefully one will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try SELECT * FROM `members` ORDER BY toonCategory;